# How to properly load a file when a function is called (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am a newbie in Python and am creating a Tkinter GUI that basically allows users to find desired keywords in .docx files. I have two buttons that both load a pickle file and only one may also add content to the file and save. After using the file under one function(button) and trying to load it up again under the other function(button) the file does not load. It will only load up again after I fully exit the program and run it again. I am not using classes for this program, but I feel that I may have to. I am just not able to bounce between these functions and successfully pass the file. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code that may be most useful for this question:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import sys,os,glob,pickle

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
root.title('Potential Candidate Engine')

Pickle_File = ('Diction.pickle')

if os.path.exists(Pickle_File):
    with open(Pickle_File,'r') as rPF:
        Dictionary = pickle.load(rPF)

def Clear_Window():
    RETURN = sys.executable
    os.execl(RETURN, RETURN, * sys.argv)

def SR():
    global Dictionary
    ### Scan the document here ###
def CNP():
    global Dictionary
    ### User adds content here, file saves ###
```

That 'Clear_Window()' function is just a workaround to return to the main window after the user is done with one function and would like to use the other. It is executed when the RETURN button is pushed

Comment: Take a look at file operations. I know that in most systems. Only one copy of the file can be opened at a time. My advise to you would be to open the file once in the program and just write to it. Only close the file when you are completely done with the file. (Exiting the program)

Comment: @Jimenemex. Certainly true on Windows, not so much on Linux systems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I read through some documentation. Could Python be possibly reading from the end of the file when I call the file to be read again?

Comment: That could be the case if you never seek back to the beginning, or if you never closed it before writing back to it again.

Comment: i used 'seek(0)', my issue still persists. Can the file technically not be opened if it's already open in the program?